# Proxy Servlet and JSESSIONID accross different domains?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, proxy

I've an architecture with Tomcat and Jetty. Jetty is behind Tomcat through a Proxy Server ( JSOS).

Browser -> Server (Tomcat) -> Proxied-Server (Jetty)

Then, some URL is actually 'proxied' to a hidden server that requires as well a session different/independant (and internal between Server & Proxied-Server ) from the original JSESSIONID (one of Tomcat).

What is the right way to do it ? can it be achieved using a ProxyServlet configuration ( http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/httpproxy.htm ) ?

Or do we need to implement a logic that is mapping between original the JESSIONID and internal JSESSIONID and connect to Proxied-Server using for example HTTP-Component ?

Thx.